# Can I use the iSight Camera as a mirror?

Tags: macos, webcam, camera, isight

Is there an OSX app that simply gives me a live feed of the iSight camera "always on top", always visible on the screen no matter what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1):

#### [Mac App Store - 3rd Eye Mirror lite](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/3rd-eye-mirror-lite/id459690364?mt=12)

[image]

Comment: Meh, I was going to build one with Quartz :(